# Do HTTP cookies have to have a value?

Tags: http, cookies

Can you have a HTTP cookie without a value?

```
ALLTHINGSGOOD=
```

The spec says without a name, it should be ignored.

> 5. If the name string is empty, ignore the set-cookie-string entirely.

But it doesn't seem to touch on what do without a value.

Comment: [_"...the (**possibly empty**) value string consists of the characters after the first %x3D ("=") character."_](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2)

Comment: @jonrsharpe edited that note into the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, empty string is a valid value. The spec says,

> 3. The (possibly empty) name string consists of the characters up to, but not including, the first `%x3D` ("=") character, and **the (possibly empty) value string consists of the characters after the first `%x3D` ("=") character.**

Practically, I would still set some kind of dummy value like "0" to avoid potential edge case bugs in some exotic browsers.